# billboard.js: timeseries with a tag demonstrated in tooltip

Tags: billboard.js

I have a time series to plot with billboard.js. The series consists of timestamp, value, and a tag. The tag is categorical (string). I would like to demonstrate the tag value in the tooltip for each point and avoid demonstrating the tag at the plot.

What is the correct recommended way to achieve this?